# my namespace is not defined. Typescript

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, namespaces, typescript

I got Visual Studio Community 2015 + Node.js Tools
I have created "Blank Node.js Console Application" Typescript project

I have added one more TypeScript file, TypeScript1.ts and put following:

```
module MyModule {
    export class Calculator {
        add(x: number, y: number): number {
            return x + y;
        };
        constructor() { }
    }
}
```

In main file, app.ts I put this:

```
/// <reference path="TypeScript1.ts" />
console.log('Hello world');
var subject: MyModule.Calculator;
subject = new MyModule.Calculator();
var result: number = subject.add(2, 3);
console.log(result);
```

It builds without issues, though when I try to debug/run, it states:

```
ReferenceError: MyModule is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1\app.js:8:15)
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing this link helped me, hope it will help u as well

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are few issues (assumes TypeScript 1.5+):

First: `/// <reference path="TypeScript1.ts" />`

Should be: `import MyModule from "./TypeScript1"`;

Second I believe you need to `export module MyModule`

Alternately you could do change

```
   module MyModule {
       export class Calculator {
           add(x: number, y: number): number {
               return x + y;
           };
           constructor() { }
       }
   }
```

To

```
       export default class Calculator {
           add(x: number, y: number): number {
               return x + y;
           };
           constructor() { }
       }
```

And then `import Calculator from "./TypeScript1";`

Or Alternately

```
       export class Calculator {
           add(x: number, y: number): number {
               return x + y;
           };
           constructor() { }
       }
```

And then `import {Calculator} from "./TypeScript1";`

Respectively depending on which of the above you chose.

The first creates the Calculator class as the primary export which is useful if the calculator is the main thing you plan to keep in the file, the second is useful if you plan to have multiple things of equal importance in the file.

Also the module keyword is generally not used as much anymore favoring instead the namespace keyword because the module keyword was too confusing and too many people confused it with file import modules.

Comment: Hello MBeatty, thanks for your reply. I have edited TypeScript1.ts:
export class Calculator {
    add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    };
    constructor() { }
}

and app.ts:
import Calculator from "TypeScript1.ts"
console.log('Hello world');
var subject: MyModule.Calculator;
subject = new MyModule.Calculator();
var result: number = subject.add(2, 3);
console.log(result);

Visual Studio underlines "TypeScript1.ts" and states "Cannot find module 'TypeScript1.ts'.". Both App1 and TypeScript1 reside in the same folder.

Comment: Two things worth trying: removing the ".ts" extension from the import statement and/or prefixing it with a "./", I'll give it a try next time I'm near my TypeScript dev setup, but if you beat me post it here and I'll make sure to edit the answer appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, looks like adding the "./" should fix it. You can either leave on or off the ".ts". Convention would be to leave it off. So convention would be import Calculator from "TypesScript1";

Comment: Also it's not causing the error but with switching to directly exporting the Calculator class you'll need to get rid of the MyModule. before Calculator in app.ts. That's not what's causing your problems but it will cause your next problem

Comment: Hi MBeatty, thanks for answers.
Do you also use Visual Studio?
I checked
`import Calculator from ".\TypeScript1";`
it states "Cannot find module '.TypeScript1', though it resides in the same folder.

**you'll need to get rid of the MyModule** - Could you explain more?

Comment: My bad, it should be "/", but not "\". After I fixed that, I got "Module <> has not default export" and I finally solved it with `import * as MyModule from "./TypeScript1";`
Here is how I call it: `var subject: MyModule.Calculator`

TypeScript1.ts contents:
`export class Calculator {
    add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y + 0 + 0;
    };
    constructor() { }
}`

Comment: I updated the answer example to correct the issue you noted and add an alternate syntax. Both of these should also solve your problem, I also generally prefer those syntaxes but I don't think any of the three syntaxes are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would check `app.js` contents if it contains code from `TypeScript1.ts` file. My guess is that it doesn't.

You can run your `tsc` as follows to fix it:

```
tsc --module commonjs --target es5 --outFile app.js TypeScript1.ts app.ts
```

Please note the `--outFile` option.

Comment: Thanks for answering Martin. app.js does not contain it. Actually, I do not need to run this file, I tried to test TypeScript1.ts file with Mocha and got the same error. Why my app.js does not contain code from TypeScript1?

Comment: Well, it's because TS compiler assumes that either you use internal modules and in that case `///<reference ...>` comments just are used to order correctly scripts from `.ts` files in final file specified by `--outFile` param. Or you use external modules where you `import` modules as you need them. (Useful resource http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files)

Comment: Thanks, I read this article before posting question, though it is quite embarrassing that I could not fully understand it. is it internal or external for me? All files are in single project. How can I achieve Mocha tests automatically build correctly to test TypeScript1.ts?

Comment: Well, there's no one answer. However, as I read about it, it seems that external modules are better if you use mocha. I would try this approach http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2015/hello-typescript-and-mocha/

Comment: I found the way to join all files into single file in Visual Studio. You have to go to project settings, open "TypeScript Build" tab and specify "Combine JavaScript output info file:" option to be able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It's now Christmas 2017 and they still haven't fixed this >:(.
Alexanders solution is correct. For "Visual Studio Code" use the following in your tsconfig.json file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "module": "system",
  "outFile": "bundle.js",
  "target": "es5"
},
```

You then run your bundled file "node bundle".

Answer (score -1):

Namespace works without even referencing...
I have used something like this...

sript1.ts

```
namespace A{
      class AA{
           var x:number;
           constructor(x:number){
                  this.x=x;
           }
      }
}
```

script2.ts

```
var y:A.AA = new A.AA(3);
```

Namespace would work even if the files are in different folders in the project. I did not reference or import any thing.